# Validate XML document with expat

Tags: c, xml, xsd, dtd, expat-parser

I have a problem with XML validation with expat. I have not found document or wiki that can help me to validate my xml document.

Is it possible to validate my XML document via xml schema (xsd file) with libexpat and a C program?

If the response is no , how to validate it via a DTD file?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also from the FAQ:

> **How can I get expat to validate my XML documents?**
>
> You can't. expat is not a validating parser.

You could try using [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/).

Answer (score 1):

From the FAQ:

> How can I get expat to read my DTD?
>
> Compile with -DXML_DTD and call XML_SetParamEntityParsing.

http://www.jclark.com/xml/expatfaq.html